# Scheduling IOHIDManager with runloop in a GUI App

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, hid, iokit

I am writing an app that is monitoring input from a gamepad in swift.
I managed to build a command-line application with the intended behavior :

```
import Foundation
import IOKit.hid

var valueCallback : IOHIDValueCallback = {
    (context, result, sender, value) in
    let element = IOHIDValueGetElement(value)
    print(IOHIDElementGetUsage(element), IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(value))
}

var attachCallback : IOHIDDeviceCallback = {
    (context, result, sender, device) in 
    IOHIDDeviceOpen(device, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice))
    IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback(device, valueCallback, context)
    print("Controller attached")
}

var detachCallback : IOHIDDeviceCallback = {
    (context, result, sender, device) in
    print("Controller detached")
}

class HID {
    let manager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone))
    let devices = [kIOHIDTransportKey: "Bluetooth"] as CFDictionary
    
    init() { 
        IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(self.manager, self.devices)
        IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(self.manager, attachCallback, nil)
        IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(self.manager, detachCallback, nil)

        IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(self.manager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue)
        IOHIDManagerOpen(self.manager, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone))
    }
}

var hidTest = HID()
CFRunLoopRun()
```

I then want to use this inside an actual app, but it then doesn't work as intended. I used the same code for the class and callbacks, and tried this in the AppDelegate :

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI
import AppKit
import IOKit.hid
import Foundation

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let contentView = ContentView()
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        let hidTest = HID()
        CFRunLoopRun()
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine, but I am not able to get any value from the gamepad. I think the problem is there : `IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(self.manager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue)` because the manager is probably not attached to the app's RunLoop.

Is there something specific I need to do to make this work ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Swift expert, but I do know about IOKit and runloops, so I'll attempt an answer.

I think it's likely there is a problem with the call to `CFRunLoopRun()`. Cocoa apps already run in a runloop which is implicitly created and run by `NSApplication`. Don't explicitly run the runloop, just allow `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to return.

When you do this, you should probably make your HID object a member of your application object or similar, or it'll be destroyed. I'm not sure if the Swift bindings for IOKit perform any automatic resource destruction; if so, this would presumably destroy the HID manager object, which you probably want to stay alive for the duration of you application's lifetime.

Comment: The object had to be declared outside of the appDidFinishLaunching, so now it works fine and `CFRunLoopRun()` is indeed not needed. Side note for people trying to do the same, sandboxing the app still permits to use IOKit, but to get HID support you strangely need to enable USB (even if your gamepad is wireless).